# $a^2=b^3+bc^4$ has no solutions in non-zero integers

Tags: number-theory

this problem is from number theory book ,

$$a^2=b^3+bc^4$$
has no  solutions in non-zero integers

This book hint ：First show that $b$ must be a perfect square.and how to do?

Comment: Dear *person that voted to close this question*: why did you vote to close this question?  Did you not think when voting to close this question that other users and the OP may want to know how they can improve the question?  Did you believe when voting to close this question that it's not important to engage with the OP and help them fix whatever flaw you thought you saw?  Please do better when voting to close questions in the future.  Sincerely, *someone that takes this site a little more seriously*.

Comment: I know it's my fault, I think you should not need so much advice

Comment: My comment was absolutely not directed toward you.  I don't think anything is your fault at all.  Someone voted to close your question, and they never left any comment for you telling you what they thought you could improve about the question.  I left my comment as a kind of "open letter" to them in the hopes that it would somehow encourage more people to communicate the reasons they are voting to close questions (or downvoting questions, where applicable).

Comment: So far the 2 who have voted to close selected the following reason: "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Comment: @user46944, This question reads to me as "*here is my problem, do it for me*". In addition, it shows very little effort on the part of OP. Prior to the edit the post contained information that was clearly not true, indicating OP didn't think much about the problem themself. The poor grammar/formatting of the post counts against OP a bit too. 

If this question does not get closed, then no harm is done. If it does get closed, then the OP will be informed of the basic reasons why with the "*This question is missing context or other details ...*" message.

Comment: @MikePierce From an administrative standpoint, do you really think the generic cookie cutter response we developed mainly for categorical voting purposes is enough?  What's the harm with you taking the 1 minute to actually notify the OP yourself what *you* find specifically wrong with their question?  Surely the generic message doesn't customize itself to every person's question.  I think saying "Oh well they get that message posted on their question anyway when its closed" is such a cop out.  Why wait for it to get closed?  You can help the OP fix the problem before it has to get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $b\ge 0$. Suppose $b\gt 1$, and let $p$ be a prime that divides $b$. Let $p^k$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $b$.

There are $2$ cases. If $p$ does not divide $c$, then since $p^{3k}$ divides $b^3$, it follows that the highest power of $p$ that divides $a^2$ is $p^k$, so $k$ is even.

If $p$ divides $c$, then the highest power of $p$ that divides $bc^4$ is $k+4t$ for some $t$.  If $3k\ne k+4t$, then the highest power of $p$ that divides $a^2$ is $p^u$, where $u=\min(3k, k+4t)$. If $k$ is odd, then $u$ is odd, impossible.

Finally, suppose $3k=k+4t$. Then $2k=4t$, so $k$ must be even.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, $(1,1,0)$ is a solution.

Comment: oh,I have edit it,

Answer (score 2):

Did the book instead say that there was no solution in naturals?

Note that $a^2 = b(b^2+c^4)$. Then, $b$ must be a perfect square (as the book hints). Let $b = d^2$. We we must also have $d^4+c^4 = a^2$, which is impossible by Fermat's Last Theorem in natural numbers. The proof of this is quite standard and involves simply bashing the formula for Pythagorean Triples and achieving Infinite Descent and can be found [here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numberfield/fermatn=4.html).

If we let $c=0$ we have the solution $(1,1,0)$ and if we let $b=0$ we have the solution $(0,0,x)$ for any $x$.

There are solutions such as $(1,1,0)$ that are integral solutions.